# What does a plus symbol mean in a relational modelling?

Tags: sql

What does a plus symbol mean when it appears next to a key in a table?

```
 ----------------------------
 TABLES
 ----------------------------
 Order        | OrderLine
 -------      | -----------
 orderid      |  orderid+
 orderdate    |  total price
              |
 ----------------------------
```

The order table and orderline table are linked through the orderid key, but I'm
not sure what the plus sign next to the orderid key in the orderline table means.

Thanks for the answer in advance.

Comment: Probably would be good to mention what kind of database or modelling tools you're using.

Comment: And what kind of modelling language is used..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the tables and the attribute names, one can hazard a guess that this stands for a foreign key.

That is, the `orderid` attribute of `OrderLine` is a foreign key to the `orderid` of the `Order` table.

Note that this is a guess based on context of the table and attribute names, in conjunction with knowledge of how `Order` and `OrderLine` entities are normally modelled.